# Split datagridview into datasets for creation of XML file with xmltextwriter

Tags: c#, datagridview, xmltextwriter

I have a datagridview table with basic address information.

From this I want to create an xml file with all the addresses in it.
But I need to order them based on the country.
So the "Address" tag should first be filled with all customers from Country1 and than country2 etc.

**Edit:**
I allready have the file writen in good order, but I need to group the address by country.
And thats where I get stuck.

Below is an example of how it could look like just for illustration.
The real question is how to part the sections based upon the country in the datagrid rows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Customers>
 <Address>
  <Addressfield1>aaa</Addressfield1>
  <Addressfield2>bbb</Addressfield2>
  <Addressfield3>ccc</Addressfield3>
  <Country>Country1</Country>
 </Address>
 <Address>
  <Addressfield1>ddd</Addressfield1>
  <Addressfield2>eee</Addressfield2>
  <Addressfield3>fff</Addressfield3>
  <Country>Country1</Country>
 </Address>
 <Address>
  <Addressfield1>ggg</Addressfield1>
  <Addressfield2>hhh</Addressfield2>
  <Addressfield3>iii</Addressfield3>
  <Country>Country2</Country>
 </Address>
 <Address>
  <Addressfield1>jjj</Addressfield1>
  <Addressfield2>kkk</Addressfield2>
  <Addressfield3>lll</Addressfield3>
  <Country>Country2</Country>
 </Address>
</Customers>
```

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: your file is not a well-formed xml. 1. Tags are not closed. 2. space is not allowed in element name.

Comment: If the DataGridView is bound to a DataTable then it's as simple as `myDataTable.WriteXml("c:\test.xml")`

Comment: I've editted my question.